# fully displayed listview in scrollview

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout, adapter

I have the following layout:

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:overScrollMode="never" >  
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_button_height"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_alpha_button"
                    android:text="@string/no_ora_inizio"
                    android:textColor="@color/labels"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size" />
        <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listTargets"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I couldn't modify the layout and inside the listview I have to add a list of adapters defined as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/alpha_white" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/counterContainer"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/labels"
        android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/counterContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSub"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_alpha_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_big_font_size" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_alpha_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_big_font_size" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the list of adapters is not fully shown.

I know that is not correct to put a ListView inside a ScrollView, I already found another thread where is suggested to use a LinearLayout instead of the ListView. I tried but with the LinearLayout the ui is properly displayed but I cannot update the adapter, the notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't update the text id/text2 that is linked to the buttons btnSub and btnAdd.

Now I'm trying to find another solution either to use the ListView or another type of view.

I've found the following a method to set the listview height:

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    if (mAdapter == null)
        return;

    int totalHeight = 0;//it is the ListView Height
    for (int i = 0, len = mAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) {
        View listItem = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        int list_child_item_height = listItem.getMeasuredHeight()+listView.getDividerHeight();//item height
        totalHeight += list_child_item_height; //
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listTargets.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (totalHeight + (listTargets.getDividerHeight() * (listTargets.getCount() - 1)));
    listTargets.setLayoutParams(params);
    listTargets.requestLayout();

}
```

but also with this method the listView height is not set as I want.

I need to have the list of adapters (the height of every adapter could be different every time) fully displayed, without any additional scrollable bar.

Do you have any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html)

**List View**

```
myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
              myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
              Helper.getListViewSize(myList);
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class Helper {
    public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
      //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        // print height of adapter on log
        Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
    }
}
```